# The abelianness of the quotient group of an abelian group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

I am working on an assignment for my abstract algebra class. The question states:

Let $A$ be an abelian group and let $B$ be a subgroup of $A$. Prove that $A/B$ is abelian.

I was under the impression that when talking about quotient groups, a homomorphism must be in the picture, but the question doesn't mention any homomorphism nor any codomain for such a homomorphism. Am I supposed to prove that $A/B$ is always abelian no matter what homomorphism is defined or is there something else to the question?

Comment: There is a "canonical" homomorphism $A\to A/B$, which you surely saw when the construction of the quotient group was discussed.

Comment: I didn't see it until a lecture or two after. I have seen it now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a homomorphism. You only need to show that $(xB)(yB)=(yB)(xB)$.

Answer (score 1):

$A/B$ consists of elements which are the cosets of $B$ in $A$. There is a standard map from $A$ to $A/B$ called the quotient map which takes and element $a \in A$ to the coset $a +B$.